# Creating your own Keras Optimizer

Tags: keras

When creating a customer Keras `Optimizer`, the workhorse function is `Optimizer.get_updates()`. I was able to create a fixed-step optimizer, but I am not sure how to do things such as running averages where I have to use values computed from previous calls of the function.

For instance, [consider `RMSprop`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L192). Isn't the accumulator being reset at each call of the function?

```
accumulators = [K.zeros(K.int_shape(p), dtype=K.dtype(p)) for p in params]
self.weights = accumulators
```

How is `RMSProp` doing the running average when the accumulator is being reset at the beginning of each update call?

Comment: It was confusing for me too when I saw the code, but that fuction is not called on every update, it is called once to build the graph, see https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5125

Comment: Also the same question than the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787873/how-adagrad-wroks-in-keras-what-does-self-weights-mean-in-keras-optimizer?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the accumulator is set to zero on each `get_updates` call. But this function is only called once, while the computational graph is built.

What is confusing is the use of symbolic functions. As Keras uses symbolic representations, what happens in `get_updates`is that a *symbolic* update is generated, in line 237-238:

```
new_a = self.rho * a + (1. - self.rho) * K.square(g)
self.updates.append(K.update(a, new_a))
```

These updates are then used while performing gradient descent. Symbolically it says that when you call updates, as in updates to a shared variable, then `a` is set to the value of `new_a` which considers the previous value of `a`. This part does the running average accumulator.

Note that multiple updates are built, one for each parameter, and then these symbolic updates are collected in a list that is returned to the caller.

Comment: It all makes sense now. Thanks a lot!